# Making a separate thread for rendering made my code slower

Tags: c++

I had a method called run in which I am updating and rendering the game objects.

```
void Run(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge) noexcept
{
    Update(pge);
    Render(pge);
}
```

Frame rate then was fluctuating 300~400 frames in release mode and 200~300 frames in debug mode. I have yet to add lodes of game logic, so I thought I would do rendering in a separate thread, so after a quick tutorial later I changed it to this.

```
void Run(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge) noexcept
    {
        Update(pge);
        std::thread renderer(&GameManager::Render, this, pge);
        renderer.join();
    }
```

Now the frame rate is around 100~150 frames in release mode and 60~100 frames in debug mode.

Comment: well threads are not seperate processor unit. Its seperate thread. They run like this - a bit of logic, a bit render, now logic, now logic, now render, render, render render logic etc.

Comment: Your program does work in another thread, but while that's happening, the main thread is simply waiting for that work to finish.

Comment: Writing multithreaded code is hard. Simply throwing threads at it doesn't magically make it faster. You have to actually write the code logic to take advantage of the parallel processing. But in any case, your code is starting a new thread and then immediately waiting on it to finish, so you are just wasting a thread, and adding all of the overhead that goes into making and cleaning up the thread. You have gained nothing at all.

Comment: You might reasonably expect the two programs to run at exactly the same speed, but your second program is slower because threading is not free. There is a cost to switching threads and to waiting on another thread to finish via join. You pay that cost even though your concurrent program does not do any work concurrently, so your program is slower overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::thread` creates a thread.
`renderer.join()` waits until the thread has finished.

Basically the same logic as your first example, but you create and destroy a thread in your 'loop'. Much more work than before, not surprising that the framerate goes down.

**What you can do:**

- define two functions, one for the update and one for the render thread
- introduce an global atomic flag

  - set it in the update function (indicates scene has been updated)
  - clear it in the render function (indicates that the changes has been presented)
- create a thread (runnable, either update or render)
- if the scene gets updated, set the flag accordingly
- the renderer can decide based on the flag to render the scene or wait until the scene gets updated or render anyway (clear the flag)
- the updater can decide based on the flag to wait until the scene has been rendered or update it anyway

**Example (c++11):**

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

atomic_bool active = true;
atomic_bool scene_flag = false;

void render(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge) noexcept
{
    while (active) {
        //while (scene_flag == false) //wait for scene update
        renderScene(pge);
        scene_flag = false; //clear flag
    }
}

void update(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge) noexcept
{
    while (active) {
        //while (scene_flag == true) //wait for scene render
        updateScene(pge);
        scene_flag = true; //set flag
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread u(update, nullptr);
    thread r(render, nullptr);

    /*while (some_condition) ...*/

    active = false;

    u.join();
    r.join();

    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: The above code could/will update the scene while it is being rendered (could/will lead to several problems). Proper synchronization is recommended.

Comment: In this approach, still only 1 thread runs at a time.

Comment: Technically two, don't forget the 'main' thread. But one 'extra' thread, yes.